# symfony2 fosuserbundle authenticate, remember me listener

Tags: symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

Okay, I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Using FOSUserBundle and Symfony 2.5.8

This listener is fired when user fills the username and password and clicks on the login button.

My `services.yml`:

```
welcomepagebundle.listener.login:
    class: TB\WelcomePageBundle\Listener\LoginListener
    arguments: [ @service_container ]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

The `TB\WelcomePageBundle\Listener\LoginListener` class:

```
class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct($container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityImplicitLogin'
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityImplicitLogin()
    {
        var_dump("please work!");die;
    }
}
```

Line 77 of RememberMeListener:

```
$this->dispatcher->dispatch(SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN, $loginEvent);
```

I would like to somehow listen for the event when user refresh the webpage and is logged in (because of session, or remember me - doesn't matter the point is that he is logged in).

Any idea?

I could listen for Controller and check if the user token exists but that doesn't seems like the best way.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Isn't your access control working properly?

Comment: I want to track "logins (visits by logged in users)"

Comment: I don't understand "logins (visits by logged in users)". Do you want to track all requests made by logged in users or just login atempts made by alredy logged in users?

Comment: Well then you need an RequestListener with security.context injected and maybe doctrine to save stats.

Comment: all requests made by logged in users, all right then I will do it as I thought at the beginning with the listener for kernel request and checking if the user is logged in) I was just looking for the best way. Thx

Comment: You basically found the answer while asking the question - listen on the INTERACTIVE_LOGIN event in your own listener and update that way.  It will be `security.interactive_login`